# Hiding a Div on Second Click li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote following code for hiding and showing divs when different li objects are clicked, everything works fine, the only problem is i would like that a div for example hides the second time i click on the very same li object clicked before... 
How can i achieve that?

```
<script> 
                $(".col-md-1-5").on("click", function() {
                    $(".containerDays").css("display", "none"); $("#" + $(this).attr("data-iddiv")).css("display", "block");
                        });
        </script>
        <script>
                $(".col-md-2").on("click", function() {
                    $(".containerTickets").css("display", "none"); $("#" + $(this).attr("data-iddiv")).css("display", "block");
                        });
        </script>
        <script>
                $(document).on('click', function (e) {
                    if ($(e.target).closest("#clubAuswahl").length === 0) {
                        $(".containerDays").hide();
                    }
                });
        </script>
        <script>
                $(document).on('click', function (e) {
                    if ($(e.target).closest(".containerDays").length === 0) {
                        $(".containerTickets").hide();
                    }
                });
        </script>
```

Comment: maybe use dbclick() ?

Comment: You need to use `toggle()` i.e. `$("#" + $(this).attr("data-iddiv")).toggle();`

Comment: add your html as well. i will be able to give you a proper solution.

Comment: You could add a variable that keeps track if something is clicked. Then use this variable in a conditional function to execute your code (which does what you want and resets the variable) if it is clicked again. Or do with it whatever you want really.

Comment: @AalindSharma my html code is too long can i anyways post it here?

Comment: @Alva can u post the html of the div which you want to work on ?

Comment: @Alva ya sure send me a link of codepen or jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: @AalindSharma There u go  https://jsfiddle.net/x8gcr6ok/2/

Comment: @AalindSharma could you checked it out? Greetings

Comment: @Alva hey buddy, sorry for late reply. i checked out the link. So can you quickly explain me, which element should be hidden on which elements click( second time click to be precise) ?

Comment: @AalindSharma Hey Aalind, thank u very much for your effort, 
 in this div: "div class="ml-xl mr-xl" id="clubAuswahl" i have 5 li elements, everything works fine right now, but i want to do is if i click on one of this li elements once (i.e. <li class="col-md-1-5 isotope-item brands" data-iddiv="clubOneDays">) it opens underneath a div containing another 7 elements (for every day of the week), but if i click on the very same element it should hide again this div....

Comment: @Alva hey buddy, check out my answer. I hope i solved what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this solves your problem. I will come up with the detailed explaination in sometime. For now enjoy and happy coding !

**EDIT 1:-**

@Alva the issue was because, the div which shows and hides, also is an li. You simply needs to update the selector by giving the class of the 7 li ( `isotope-item`) inside the selector.Checkout the updated code.

```js
$(document).on('click','#clubAuswahl li.isotope-item',function(){
            var idToToggle = $(this).attr('data-iddiv');
            var self = this;
            $(self).closest('#clubAuswahl').find('li').each(function(){
             var tempIdToHide = $(this).attr('data-iddiv');
             if( this != self ){
              $('#' +tempIdToHide).hide();
             }
            })
         $('#'+idToToggle).toggle();
        });
```

Comment: Hey Aalind thank you very much works fine, but now i have the next problem, i have another divs form class containerTickets that are underneath the div from class containerDays and i cannot click them anymore because they hide as sonn as i click on one of those li elements...

Comment: @Alva so happy to know that it solved your problem. Please upvote it if you have some time. Also, please post your other problem  as a seperate question( and share a link in the comment here) as it will help other users differentiate with different problems.

Comment: in the jfiddle i posted before you can see what happened when i click on each element of the site...

Comment: @Alva hey buddy. I got the problem with the previous solution. Please have a look at the edit 1.

Comment: Aalind, everything works prefectly now ! THank u very much bro!

Comment: @Alva great to know that it works.  Please upvote if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle(); to hide element on second click (if first one makes it visible)

Like so

```
$(".col-md-1-5").on("click", function() {
  $(".containerDays").toggle(); 
  $("#" + $(this).attr("data-iddiv")).toggle();
});
```

Or .slideToggle(); to add some nice animation to hide/show

Comment: function slide toogle adds a nice animation but, i think thats why i didn't use the toogle function, im controlling different divs depending on which element of the list are clicked, when i use toogle it shows me all the divs appended to all elemenst of my list

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a flag variable (class?) to keep track if the first click has already happened on the given element:

```
$(".col-md-2").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("helper")){ //if my helper class is already there, this means firts click has already happended
      $(".containerTickets").css("display", "none"); 
      $("#" +  $(this).attr("data-iddiv")).css("display", "block");
      $(this).removeClass("helper");
    }else{ //otherwise, I add to my element the helper class
      $(".containerTickets").css("display", "block"); 
      $("#" +  $(this).attr("data-iddiv")).css("display", "none");
      $(this).addClass("helper");
    }
});
```

Comment: i want to show different divs when clicked on the different elements .col-md-1-5 or .col-md-2 and hide thosse divs when clicken on the very same element for the second time... i think dbclick is not what im looking for...

Comment: at first try it looks good but i have to click two times to hide a div, when i click the first element shows me a div, when i click the second elemnt it should hide the first div an show me the next div, and when i click the same element twice then it should hide the div, but somehow it is not working properly, here its my code on jfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x8gcr6ok/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tov0t159/ your fiddle didn't work beacuse there wasn't jquery

Comment: on the javascript window u have to set framework to 1.9 and select all options underneath, it should work just tried it myself